# OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

I have seen versions of this problem, but haven't found a solution in them.
I'm new to OpenCV so this problem might be obvious.

Whenever I try to run my script for lane detection, (works fine for images) on the frames of a video, I get the error:

```
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
    Overload resolution failed:
     - src data type = object is not supported
     - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

The code being used here is:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
while cap.isOpened():
    boo, frame = cap.read()
    frame_c = np.copy(frame)
    edge = edge_det(frame_c)
    region = roi(edge)
    detected = overlay_line(frame_c, region)
    cv2.imshow("current", detected)
    if cv2.waitKey(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))-3) & 0xFF == "q":
        break
```

The error occurs in the `edge_det` function:

```
def edge_det(image):
    result = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    result = cv2.Canny(result, 50, 150)
    return result
```

The frames are being displayed fine, but they are being displayed as they were with no updates from my code. This is probably a problem with how reading a frame in a video (with `cap.read`) is different from an image with `img.imread`.

The same code (with the exception of the read function) when applied on an image gives straight coloured lines across lanes.

The result with the video frames though is that they are being displayed as they originally were.

Comment: did you check if your frame is not empty or something? What's the value of `boo`. Did you do any debugging? I had a suspicion about `np.copy()` but turns out it does the same as `frame.copy()`

Comment: yea, the boo is true if the frame has been read, if there was any mistake there, there won't have been any display (original or code updated)

Comment: You cannot do on fly `region = roi(edge)`., while video is playing. You need to do pause and edit, then do `roi`.

Answer (score 0):

i do think your guess is right:
reading images and reading videos is different:

```py
# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is taken from the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name.

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('chaplin.mp4')
```

or full example found [here](https://learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('chaplin.mp4')

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```